# Which shell npm is using when running npm scripts?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, npm, fish

I am on Windows running fish shell through ConEmu. Fish by default doesn't recognize "&&" operator *however* having this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo 'a' && echo 'b'"
}
```

and running "npm run test" is working. 
So I thought it must be using default "cmd" and this is what `npm config ls -l | grep shell` says, however....
When I change "test" script to:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo 'a' && ls"
}
```

this also works while `ls` is clearly not supported in "cmd".

What the hell is going here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks line `npm run` sends the command to the `sh` shell, which usually points to the default Bourne-compatible shell. I don't have experience with your emulator, but I would bet it's using `bash` in your environment (since Fish is not Bourne-compatible).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what shell is used in your case, nor what is the preferred way to check which shell is npm using, but I have some general hints, which might help.

You can try

```
{ 
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo $0" 
  }
}
```

which can produce results like:

```
$ npm run test

> @ test /home/matmat/test
> echo $0

sh
```

(for bash on linux)

or

```
C:\Users\qbolec\Documents\test>npm run test

> @ test C:\Users\qbolec\Documents\test
> echo $0

$0
```

on Windows Node.js command prompt.

You could also try

```
  "test": "which ls"
```

to get some more info.